# Looking for cloud hosting similar to QGIS cloud

Tags: software-recommendations, cloud-gis, qgis-cloud

I have about 6 or 7 large clients who each require some form of personalised online mapping service.

My aim is to produce a secure login required database for each client using my shapefiles and open source mapping.  In essence something like QGIS Cloud, but that i have full control over.

When i make a change to the shapefile it should update on the online map.

All the online map needs to do is have layer control, basic query, measure and print.  print composer will be standard with my company's logo on each print and theirs.

also there will be no editing function, and display style will be set by me.

QGIS Clouds limits are too constrictive.

Comment: QGIS Cloud Pro http://www.qgiscloud.com/en/pages/plans €65 per month

Comment: Its pro i want but size limits are too small. i think.

Comment: update your question with the limits - contacting qgis cloud would be a good start - limits can be raised if you ask.

Comment: You can use PostgreSQL (+PostGIS) and serve your files as WFS with GeoServer. You can visualize the WFS with Leaflet. Layer control, basic query, measure and print is also all possible with Leaflet.

Comment: Look at NextGIS Web (you can play with free Web GIS account on http://nextgis.com/) and if like this solution install on your own server.

Answer (score -1):

Gishosting is a new solution (the website is only in Italian, but you can also ask for information in English)

http://www.gishosting.gter.it

GisHosting is based on 
- QGIS Server as application server
- Lizmap Web Client ad client https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-web-client
- a plugin of QGIS (lizmap) to set the option of the webgis client

A PostgreSQL/PostGIS geodatabase is optionally available and the data sync with the hosting server is normally guarantee by [nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) application

Comment: Do you work for them, by any chance? You might want to add a bit more information about the capabilities of gishosting.

Comment: GisHosting use a linux ubuntu server with QGIS server and Lizmap webclient. So the final user work only on a QGIS desktop project and can publish a map on the web simply working on a network folder of its PC. Also a PostGIS DB can be included in the subscription. The first month is free, after the user can the user can choose their offer from 25 € / month (VAT excluded)